# problem using sklearn.pipeline with GaussianNB

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, linearmodels

I want to test a sentiment model

this is a part of my code.

```
sentiment_model = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(binary=False, strip_accents='ascii', stop_words=stop_words_Evaluacion_entre_Pares, ngram_range=(1,2))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
    ('clf', GaussianNB()),
])
```

but I have the next error

```
A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

when I use

```
sentiment_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

or I get this error

```
TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

when I try to use

```
sentiment_model.predict_proba(['text here...'])
```

any solution?

Comment: using Countvectorizer with tfidftransformer is same as using TfidfVectorizer...so if u want to use Tfidftransformer use countvectorizer for vectorizing text data.

Comment: u need to pass x and y sentiment_model.fit(x,y)

Comment: thanks @qaiser CountVectorizer works fine... I am kind of new here. How can I marke ur comment as a correct answer?